# jQuery select element in sibling's "td"

Tags: jquery

HTML is

```
<tr>  
    <td><input /></td>  
    <td><a>ref</a></td>  
</tr>
```

I got
`$('a')`

What is the most optimal way to get `<input />` from this ?
If they are together `<input /><a></a>`, i can use `$('a').sibling('input')`, but they are in different td's

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: optimal can be a subjective perspective, as evidenced by the answers given. Of course, mine is the most optimal ;-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('a').closest('td').siblings().find('input')
```

This goes up to the `<td>`, and searches siblings for `<input>` elements.

Answer (score 7):

Another variation

```
var input = $('a').closest('tr').find('td input');
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$('a').parent().prev().children('input')
```